# Ubuntu 13.04 Network Configuration

Tags: wireless, networking, configuration, dhcp

I recently bought a new Linksys E3200 router, and after much trouble, got it working, but I can only connect to it via Static wireless settings in my Connections Manager. I want it to be DHCP (Automatic), but then it automatically disconnects.

Also, I edited my /etc/network/interfaces to include:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dynamic
```

Which causes me to receive the warning "Now booting without network configuration".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of put this:

```
iface eth0 inet dynamic
```

Put this:

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```